# Getting property of object inside array inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object that when i print it with console.log without stringify it looks like this:

```
SuiteStats {
type: 'suite',
start: 2019 - 06 - 04T13: 04: 10.640Z,
_duration: 6262,
uid: 'District1',
cid: '0-0',
title: 'District',
fullTitle: undefined,
tests: [],
hooks: [],
suites:
[SuiteStats {
        type: 'suite',
        start: 2019 - 06 - 04T13: 04: 15.271Z,
        _duration: 1621,
        uid: 'Create District5',
        cid: '0-0',
        title: '@sanity, @sanityUpgraded, @debug: Create District',
        fullTitle: undefined,
        tests: [Array],
        hooks: [],
        suites: [],
        end: 2019 - 06 - 04T13: 04: 16.892Z
    }
],
end: 2019 - 06 - 04T13: 04: 16.902Z
```

}

now I want to get the title of SuiteStats that is inside suites that is inside SuiteStats (it value is: '@sanity, @sanityUpgraded, @debug: Create District')

```
console.log(SuiteStats.suites[0].title
```

does not work, it exits with an error about "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

I tried other way without success, like:

```
console.log(SuiteStats.suites[0].SuiteStats.title
```

so what I am doing wrong, and why this object is different from another object I worked with in the past?

this is how the object looks after stringify:

```
{
"type": "suite",
"start": "2019-06-04T13:29:25.385Z",
"_duration": 5575,
"uid": "District1",
"cid": "0-0",
"title": "District",
"tests": [],
"hooks": [],
"suites": [{
        "type": "suite",
        "start": "2019-06-04T13:29:29.737Z",
        "_duration": 1220,
        "uid": "Create District5",
        "cid": "0-0",
        "title": "@sanity, @sanityUpgraded, @debug: Create District",
        "tests": [{
                "type": "test",
                "start": "2019-06-04T13:29:29.745Z",
                "_duration": 369,
                "uid": "I am logged in as admin user \"ufedadmin\"7",
                "cid": "0-0",
                "title": "I am logged in as admin user \"ufedadmin\"",
                "output": [],
                "state": "passed",
                "end": "2019-06-04T13:29:30.114Z"
            }, {
                "type": "test",
                "start": "2019-06-04T13:29:30.122Z",
                "_duration": 523,
                "uid": "I create or overwrite District \"Argentina3\" with code \"Argentina3\"8",
                "cid": "0-0",
                "title": "I create or overwrite District \"Argentina3\" with code \"Argentina3\"",
                "output": [],
                "state": "passed",
                "end": "2019-06-04T13:29:30.645Z"
            }, {
                "type": "test",
                "start": "2019-06-04T13:29:30.667Z",
                "_duration": 283,
                "uid": "I expect that district \"Argentina3\" was created9",
                "cid": "0-0",
                "title": "I expect that district \"Argentina3\" was created",
                "output": [],
                "state": "passed",
                "end": "2019-06-04T13:29:30.950Z"
            }
        ],
        "hooks": [],
        "suites": [],
        "end": "2019-06-04T13:29:30.957Z"
    }
],
"end": "2019-06-04T13:29:30.960Z"
```

}

Comment: Your array looks invalid to me `[SuiteStats {` ? Are you sure you're not trying to access the stringified version of your data?

Comment: this JSON looks invalid, can you stringify it and share?

Comment: I shared the object after stringify in the question itself, thanks.

Comment: the 'suites' array is empty, did you intend to read from the 'tests' array?

Comment: @AlonYampolski there is another suites before the empty one that is not empty

Comment: @NickParsons i am not accessing the stringified one. when i do SuiteStats.suites[0] i get the content ok. the problem is when i try to access the title property

Comment: i'm looking at the stringified JSON you uploaded and it looks like its empty "suites": []! is the stringified version the same as the object you are working with?

Comment: @AlonYampolski my bad uploaded wrong string, already fixed now

Comment: `SuiteStats` is the type of the object you are printing, not a node in the data. Look at the stringified version of the data to see what the names of the nodes are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's working fine:

```js
var data = {
"type": "suite",
"start": "2019-06-04T13:29:25.385Z",
"_duration": 5575,
"uid": "District1",
"cid": "0-0",
"title": "District",
"tests": [],
"hooks": [],
"suites": [{
        "type": "suite",
        "start": "2019-06-04T13:29:29.737Z",
        "_duration": 1220,
        "uid": "Create District5",
        "cid": "0-0",
        "title": "@sanity, @sanityUpgraded, @debug: Create District",
        "tests": [{
                "type": "test",
                "start": "2019-06-04T13:29:29.745Z",
                "_duration": 369,
                "uid": "I am logged in as admin user \"ufedadmin\"7",
                "cid": "0-0",
                "title": "I am logged in as admin user \"ufedadmin\"",
                "output": [],
                "state": "passed",
                "end": "2019-06-04T13:29:30.114Z"
            }, {
                "type": "test",
                "start": "2019-06-04T13:29:30.122Z",
                "_duration": 523,
                "uid": "I create or overwrite District \"Argentina3\" with code \"Argentina3\"8",
                "cid": "0-0",
                "title": "I create or overwrite District \"Argentina3\" with code \"Argentina3\"",
                "output": [],
                "state": "passed",
                "end": "2019-06-04T13:29:30.645Z"
            }, {
                "type": "test",
                "start": "2019-06-04T13:29:30.667Z",
                "_duration": 283,
                "uid": "I expect that district \"Argentina3\" was created9",
                "cid": "0-0",
                "title": "I expect that district \"Argentina3\" was created",
                "output": [],
                "state": "passed",
                "end": "2019-06-04T13:29:30.950Z"
            }
        ],
        "hooks": [],
        "suites": [],
        "end": "2019-06-04T13:29:30.957Z"
    }
],
"end": "2019-06-04T13:29:30.960Z"
};

console.log(data.suites[0].title);
```

Comment: yes it works when you copy the string like you did, but it does not work when doing:

Answer (score 0):

I think its fine. 
To troubleshoot your object here is an idea you can use

```
var object = your_json;
var array  = object.suites;
console.log(array.length); //confirm array !empty

//lets see if we can get all the titles
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    console.log(array[i].title);
}

//since you explicitly know that this is an array of objects. check keys and values 
for (var key in array) {
    var value = array[key];
    console.log(key, value);
}

//troubleshooting: if you think the value is an array write a recursive function
function my_recursive_function(array){
    for(var key in array) {
        var value = array[key];
        if(Array.isArray(value)){
            my_recursive_function(value)
        }else{
            console.log(key, value);
        }            
    }
}
```